PCRE2 named group capture array
I have a problem with the PCRE2 regex engine. When a named group appears several times in a text it only captures the last appearance of the group.
Example:
Regex pattern \w+\s(?<subgroup>(\d))*
Text hello 23
this will match correctly but only the number 3 will be captured as subgroup (subgroup = 3)
screenshot from regex101.com
When using the .NET regex engine both subgroup matched are captured (subgroup.1 = 2, subgroup.2 = 3)
.NET regex engine capture result
However, I need to use the PCRE2 engine for my project.
Addition
Here is a more complex example where I need this to work:
/(?<topgroup>(?<maingroup>(((?:\h)?(Ab|Ba)(?:\h)?)(?<subgroup>([\d]{1,3}((?:\h)?[a-rt-z])?)|[A-Ra-rT-Zt-z](?:\h))(?:\h))*)(?<endgroup>FOO|BAR))/g

Example text: Ab 2 Ba 3g Ab 3a FOO
I need the entire text to be captured in topgroup.
'Ab 2 Ba 3g Ab 3a' in maingroup and
2, 3g and 3a in subgroup
But as for now only 3a is captured in subgroup
https://regex101.com/r/WXYAvP/1
Does anyone have an idea if PCRE2 allows for an "array" of named groups to be capture - I could not find the information in the Perl docs myself.
Would greatly appreciate any advice!

Try it like this (?:[a-z]+\h|\G(?!^))(?<subgroup>\d)\h* https://regex101.com/r/3GVuG3/1 Note that \w also matches a digit.

Yes, (?:\w+\s+|\G(?!^))\s*\K\d can work, too, with a function to get multiple matches, if you just need numbers and you know the \w+ will match what you expect. You can alway replace \w+ with \p{L}+ to match one or more letters.

Thank you for your help! The patterns you mention do work with the simple example I mentioned - but they do not work for my specific problem which is a bit more complex. I added another example that comes closer to what I am actually trying to achieve - sorry I should have done that earlier.

If you have multiple alternations, you might use the J flag to allow duplicate subpattern names, but if you are repeating a capture group you will only capture the value of the last iteration. I think pcre does not have an option like that as .NET has captured subgroups.

PCRE2 doesn't return an "array" of repeated captures for a same group.
As explained in comments, you have to use several consecutive matches to obtain what you want with this kind of pattern:
(?Jnxx)
( # first branch: to catch consecutive sub groups with contiguous matches
    \G (?!\A)
  | # second branch: to catch top, main, end groups and the first sub group
    (*positive_lookahead:
        (?<top> \b
            (?<main>
                (
                    \h? ( Ab | Ba ) \h?
                    (?<sub>
                        (?> [0-9]{1,3} ( \h? [ a-r t-z ] )? )
                      |
                        [ A-R a-r T-Z t-z ]
                    ) \b
                )*
            )
            \h
            (?<end> FOO | BAR )
        )
    )
)
\h? ( Ab | Ba ) \h? \K
(?<sub> \g<sub> )

demo
\G (aka Glue) ensures that consecutive matches are contiguous. It's an assertion that fails when the next match doesn't start exactly at the end of the previous.
The J modifier allows a named group to be defined several times in a same pattern.
With the n modifier, all parts enclosed between parenthesis without a name are seen as non-capturing groups (like (?: ... )).
When a pattern starts to be long, please use the x modifier and indent it, and comment it. You can also use the xx modifier if you want spaces to be ignored inside character classes too.
